# Getting 503 error with restassured testing

Tags: api, web-api-testing

I have started using restassured for my rest apis testing recently but for simple GET method also I am getting 503 error everytime same request works fine with Manual tools

Comment: were you able to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

503 is Service is not Available... So I guess your service was not running properly or you just sent an invalid request with RestAssured.